# Lightdm locking session on suspend when it should not

Tags: systemd, gnome, suspend, lightdm, light-locker

For some reason whenever the computer suspends it locks the session and I have to log back in. I'm trying to configure my own lockscreen so this is undesired. Lightlocker is installed but disabled. The behaviour occurs both when closing the lid or suspending manually with systemd or gnome.

Edit: narrowed it down to it being just lightdm. GDM does not lock on its own.

Comment: Check the `privacy`section of the Gnome Settings Manager.

Comment: @Mioriin didn't fix it, but thanks for the suggestion